# JQuery adds unwanted div after an ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have an jquery ajax call where I add a new comment to a database. It saves just fine but when i want to reaload the div where the comments are shown, I always get an additional div which I do not want. When I reaload the page everything is just fine and displayed as wanted!

The script:

```
<script>
        $("#addcmt").click(function() {
            var UserID = $("#UserID").val();
            var ClassID = $("#ClassID").val();
            var text = $("#appendedInputButton").val();
            var option;
            if($("#option").is(':checked')) {
                option = 3;
            } else {

                option = 1;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/comment/functions/add_class_comment.php",
                data: "text=" + text + "&UserID=" + UserID + "&ClassID=" + ClassID + "&option=" + option,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#CommentList").load(location.href+' #CommentList');
                    $('#appendedInputButton').val("");
                    $('.criticalcomment').attr('checked', false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The php+html where they comments are shown:

```
<div class="bs-docs-example" id="message">
    <div id="CommentList">
        <?php
            for ($i=0; $i<$l; $i++) {
                switch($commentarr[$i]->getOption()) {
                    case 1:
                        $option="alert-success";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $option="alert-info";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $option="alert-error";
                }
                echo '<div class="Comments alert '.$option.'"><div class="CommentsName">'.$userarr[$i]->getFirstname().' '.$userarr[$i]->getLastname().'</div>';
                echo '<div class="CommentsDate">'.renderDate($commentarr[$i]->getDate()).'</div><div class="CommentsText">'.$commentarr[$i]->getText().'</div>';
                if ($deletebutton == 1) {
                    echo '<div class="deleteButtonAdmin"><input type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary delcmt" value="L&ouml;schen" name="'.$commentarr[$i]->getID().'"></div>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <form class="Comments postmessage">
        <div class="input-append" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="ClassID" id="ClassID" value="<?php echo $c->getID(); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="UserID" id="UserID" value="<?php echo $u->getID(); ?>">
            <textarea class="span12" name="text" id="appendedInputButton" type="text"></textarea>
            <label for="option">Kritisch?</label><input type="checkbox" id="option" class="criticalcomment" name="option" value="1">
            <input type="button" class="btn" id="addcmt" value="Post">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I hope someone got an idea or hint for me!

Comment: What is the content of that additional div you are getting?

Comment: Can you add the code with extra `div` that you got. You may obtain it using firebug.

Comment: what is the last `echo '</div>';` for??

Comment: @rps it closes `<div class="Comments alert '`

Comment: I actually get this when I add a new comment:

<div id="CommentList">
  <div id="CommentList">
    <div class="Comments alert alert-success">
      <div class="CommentsName">Martini</div>
      <div class="CommentsDate">23.08.2013 17:20</div>
      <div class="CommentsText">Comment</div>
      <div class="deleteButtonAdmin"><input type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary delcmt" value="Löschen" name="567"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

so i think the second CommentList-div (which should be the first and/or only) is nested in an additional - unwanted - div!

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$("#CommentList").load(location.href+' #CommentList');` tells jQuery to replace the *contents* of `#CommentList` with `#CommentList`, so you get two nested `#CommentList`s, correct?

You might have to do `$("#CommentList").remove().load(location.href+' #CommentList')`. If that does not work, try introducing a temporary div:

```
$("<div />").load(location.href+' #CommentList', function (div) {
    $('#CommentList').replaceWith($(div));
})
```

Comment: You could do: `location.href+' #CommentList .Comments'`

Comment: @Brian: yeah that's right! your first suggestion won't work! it removes everything and i can't see anything anymore!

Comment: @MartiniMalone sorry, `.load` is very situation-dependent. My recommendation is actually to skip using it altogether and opt for `.ajax`, where you have to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this after loading the div!

```
 $("#CommentList").find('div').unwrap(); or
 $("#CommentList").find('#CommentList').unwrap();//I am doubtful about this
```